# Robertson-Walker metric and stable orbits

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, spacetime-dimensions

The RW metric is defined using 4 spatial dimensions, but stable planetary orbits require 3 spatial dimensions. Does this indicate a problem with the assumption of the RW metric to describe the cosmos?

Comment: It has 3 spatial dimensions, not 4.

Comment: Is the *Robertson-Walker metric* different to the FLRW metric or FRW metric or Friedmann equations or however you want to attribute it? If not, it has 3 spacelike and 1 timelike dimension.

Comment: See eqn (2) here: http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/phys5770_08/frw.pdf

Comment: That shows the embedding of the **spatial part of the metric**  within a 4D **spatial** manifold. Embedding is quite a common way to illustrate hypersurfaces, e.g. embeddings are frequently used to illustrate the de Sitter and AdS metrics.

Comment: Thanks John. So I take it that the embedding dimension isn't real; it's just illustrative.

Comment: Yes. The manifold used for the embedding is a mathematical device and is not intended to represent anything real.

Comment: I close this question (v2) as its current form (v2) appears to be not useful for the community, since on one hand, it asks about a fifth physical dimension, while on another hand, the fifth dimension turns out to be only a visualization aid. I would be happy to reopen this question if the logic line could somehow be unfolded.

Answer (score 0):

The FRW spacetime can be written as ${\bf R} \times {\bf \Sigma}$ where ${\bf R}$ where ${\bf R}$ represents the time direction and ${\bf \Sigma}$ is a homogeneous and isotropic three-manifold representing the spatial dimensions. This means that for every time there is a corresponding hypersurface for space.

To help with the visualisation of hypersurfaces it's quite common to embed them in a manifold on one higher dimension. For example the de Sitter and Anti-de Sitter metrics are commonly represented as hyperboloids in a 5D space. The article you link is describing the embedding of ${\bf \Sigma}$ in a 4D Euclidean space. That's why at first glance it appears that there are four spacelike dimensions.